# How far has a black hole to be in order for its tidal forces to disintegrate earth?

Tags: black-holes, newtonian-gravity, tidal-effect

I don't know if this question can be answered to honest but I though I might try ask just in case someone can calculate that.
What I need to know here is how strong should the tidal forces be to start separating chunks of earth and therefore determine how far this force can be from a black hole.
My assumption here is a 10 solar masses black hole.

Comment: Related:http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109505/

Comment: As Indicated by @Bitrex's link the search term you are looking for is "Roche Limit". Mind you the atmosphere is pulled off first because it can be treated as having slightly negative tensile strength. Quick, someone switch MegaMaid to the other mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distance at which the tidal forces froma  primary start tearing apart a satellite is known as the [Roche limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit). In calculating the Roche limit we assume that the yield stress of the rock making up the planet is small compared to the gravitational forces at work so it can be ignored. The question is then simply whether the gravity of the body (in this case the Earth) is stronger than the tidal forces trying to pull it apart. This makes the calculation fairly simple, and as I calculated in [Roche Limits and black holes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109505/roche-limits-and-black-holes) the equation for the Roche limit in terms of the primary mass $M$ is:

$$
\begin{align}
 d &= \left( 2 \frac{\frac{3M}{4\pi}}{\rho} \right) ^{1/3} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

where $\rho$ is the density of the satellite. The Earth doesn't have a uniform density so the calculation is going to be rather rough, but we can use the average density, [which is $5514$ kg/m$^3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth). Ten solar masses is $1.99 \times 10^{31}$ kg, and feeding these values into equation (1) we get:

$$ d \approx 1.2 \times 10^9 \text{m} $$

For comparison this is about 0.8% of the distance from the Earth to the Sun.

Given the approximations involved in calculating this you should regard it as an order of magnitude estimate. In any case the destruction of the earth would be progressive. First the atmosphere would be torn off, then the seas and then the mantle. The iron core would be the last to go.

One last comment, you ask about a ten solar mass black hole, but the body doesn't need to be a black hole. The event horizon of a ten solar mass black hole would be about 30,000m so the earth would be torn apart well before it got anywhere near the event horizon. A ten solar mass neutron star would be just as destructive.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you.
Just one last thing that confuses me, and forgive me if it sounds too ignorant. That thing is, where do these torn apart pieces of earth end up ?
I've read about the Roche limit and as far as I understood, when the satellite is disintegrated, it keeps orbiting the primary, so is this the case with the black hole too ? just orbiting around it ?
I mean, it is commonly known that objects "fall in" black holes, so will these pieces of earth ever reach the event horizon of the black hole ?

Comment: @AbanobEbrahim: yes, the pieces of the Earth would form a ring much like Saturn's rings. As long as you stay more that 3 times the event horizon radius away you will stay in a stable orbit just like orbiting a star. Once you're closer than $3 r_s$ there are no stable orbits, but that's a question for another day!

Comment: Is the 3 times the event horizon figure for the 10 solar masses black hole only or it is a general rule for all black holes ?

Comment: @AbanobEbrahim: That's a general rule for all black holes, though of course the event horizon depends on the mass of the black hole. Specifically $r_s = 2GM/c^2$.

Comment: And no stable orbit means that the pieces of the Earth will fall into the black hole, correct ?

Comment: @AbanobEbrahim: the Earth will break up far, far outside the event horizon. At about $10^5$ times the event horizon distance in fact. That means the pieces will occupy stable orbits because they'll never get close enough to the event horizon to encounter the unstable region. It's really hard to get that close to a black hole because you have to shed an enormous amount of angular momentum. For all everyday purposes orbits around a black hole are perfectly stable.

Comment: In fact, a ten solar mass neutron star would be a lot more destructive, because then, you'd have that NS supernova immanently happening.  :)